# How to accumulate data from muliple ajax calls in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to accumulate data from different ajax calls and then display it in a div. Right now I have this:

```
//residents is an array of urls
function doResidentsRequest(residents) {
    for(let i = 0; i < residents.length; i++) {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                let residentData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                displayResidents(residentData);
                console.log(residentData);
            }
        };
        let url = residents[i];
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

function displayResidents(residentsData) {
        document.getElementById("modal-content").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', residentsData["name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try promise.all() function. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
Also fetch api from javascript is much efficient than xmlhttp.